# reledmac and koma and space before and after section

Tags: koma-script, reledmac

I have problems with the spacing of the section command in reledmac. This

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{reledmac}

% Section 
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=15em,
  afterskip=1em]{section}

\begin{document}

\addchap{1891}

        \section{Diary, 27. 4. 1891}\beginnumbering\pstart
           Met him in a bar\pend
           \endnumbering
        \section{Diary, 28. 4. 1891}\beginnumbering\pstart
          Was rather happy.\pend
           \pstart
           But not for long.\pend
           \endnumbering                            

\end{document}
```

does not produce the desired output before and after the section command (the \section isn't even inside the reledmac part).

notice the missing space before the second section command:
[image: output with reledmac. notice the missing space before section]

When I add \listfiles to the code, this is the log-file:

> > This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)  \write18 enabled. entering extended mode
> >     (./loesch.tex LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3 Babel <3.9r> and
> >     hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
> >     (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
> >     Document Class: scrbook 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script document class
> >     (book)
> >     (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
> >     (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
> >     (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
> >     (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
> >     Package scrlfile, 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
> >                       Copyright (C) Markus Kohm
>
> )))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
>   Package typearea, 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (type area)
>                     Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
>                     Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-
>
> ))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlayer-scrpage.sty
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlayer.sty))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/reledmac/reledmac.sty
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xargs/xargs.sty)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bigfoot/suffix.sty)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/ragged2e.sty
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everysel.sty))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
>   (./loesch.aux) ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros chapter
>   without number Section 1 (./loesch.1) (./loesch.eledsec1) Section 2
>   (./loesch.2) (./loesch.eledsec2)
>   [1{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updma
>   p/pdftex.map}] (./loesch.aux)
>
> *File List*  scrbook.cls    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script document
>   class (book) scrkbase.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package
>   (KOMA-Script-dependent bas ics and keyval usage)  scrbase.sty
>   2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b asics
>   and keyval usage)   keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser
>   (DPC) scrlfile.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (loading
>   files) tocbasic.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (handling
>   toc-files) scrsize11pt.clo    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script font size
>   class option (11pt) typearea.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script
>   package (type area) scrlayer-scrpage.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21
>   KOMA-Script package (end user interfac e for scrlayer) scrlayer.sty
>   2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (defining layers and page 
>   styles)    babel.sty    2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package  english.ldf
>   2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system reledmac.sty
>   2016/10/04 v2.16.1 typesetting critical editions  xkeyval.sty
>   2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)  xkeyval.tex
>   2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)    xargs.sty    2008/03/22 v1.1
>   extended macro definitions  (mpg) etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a
>   e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)   suffix.sty    2006/07/15 1.5a Variant
>   command support  xstring.sty    2013/10/13  v1.7c  String
>   manipulations (C Tellechea) ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides
>   the ifluatex switch (HO) ragged2e.sty    2009/05/21 v2.1 ragged2e
>   Package (MS) everysel.sty    2011/10/28 v1.2 EverySelectfont Package
>   (MS)  ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
>   loesch.1   loesch.eledsec1   loesch.2   loesch.eledsec2  ***********
>
> )
>
> > Output written on loesch.pdf (1 page, 24203 bytes). SyncTeX written on loesch.synctex.gz. Transcript written on loesch.log.

Comment: It works here with texlive 2016. Which error do you get? Please edit your question.

Comment: @KeksDose I did so. It's not an error but an unwanted output

Comment: I took away the picture of the desired ouput. Is it clear now?

Comment: Works for me too (also TeXLive 2016). Can you add `\listfiles` somewhere in your document and post the output?

Comment: Both versions (with `\baselineskip` or 15em`work here.

Comment: that is strange! i installed all the updates and I just recreated it with a new file. can the reason be that I also upgraded to MacOS Sierra?

Comment: Now I'm totally confused, because when I try the code at Overleaf.com this doesn't compile correctly as well, so it's not my computer. There is no error, but the beforeskip=15em is not visible at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a `\leavevmode` after `\endnumbering`.

Is it not included in reledmac because I am afraid to break backward compatibility.

```
\section{Diary, 27. 4. 1891}\beginnumbering\pstart
           Met him in a bar\pend
           \endnumbering
         \leavevmode  
        \section{Diary, 28. 4. 1891}\beginnumbering\pstart
          Was rather happy.\pend
           \pstart
           But not for long.\pend
           \endnumbering
```