# leavevmode, section and pagebreaks

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, reledmac

I have several letters, some very short, in my book, typeset with scrbook, reledmac and `\raggedbottom`. `\chapter` is used for *years* and `\section` is used for an *individual letter*.

I need the `leavevmode` command as it resets some things when the number of letters get too high. But this introduces an unwanted pagebreak after the letter title. Why is that so? And how can I tweak the section command to act as wanted?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\chapter{Letters from 1900}
\leavevmode\pagebreak[3]\section{Letter 1}\nopagebreak[3]
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\leavevmode\pagebreak[3]\section{Letter 2}\nopagebreak[3]
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\leavevmode\pagebreak[3]\section{Letter 3}\nopagebreak[3]
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

This is the unwanted result:
[image: unwanted page break]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't understand why you are using `\leavevmode` at all?! Of course, if you take out `\leavevmode` then the problem disappears. What "things" are you trying to reset by using `\leavevmode`? I suspect that there are better ways to reset them but it is hard to say without knowing what they are...

Comment: latex never breaks after a section heading but you have `\pagebreak[3]` almost forcing a page break after the chapter heading and `\nopagebreak[3]` allowing a page break after section headings.  What is the intention of these (just removing them would appear to be the answer)

Comment: Of course I could try to avoid the leavevmode and I don't remember what made me include it in the first place. But when I remove leavevmode from my real project it won't compile the nearly 30.000 lines as it constantly hangs itself.

Comment: the `\leavemode` looks wrong but it is the `\[no]pagebreak` that is allowing the  page break.

Comment: I believe it's because reledmac sets it's text as block, thus creating a page break chance. removing the (no)pagebreaks does not work

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\beginnumbering` does also allow a page break.

Comment: @Schweinebacke probably should fix that rather than add \nopagebreak in the document:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have not defined it. I could patch `\beginnumbering` but I don't know whether or not all `\beginnumbering` should be changed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I found why I included \leavevmode: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332859/reledmac-and-koma-and-space-before-and-after-section but I'll try Schweinebackes solution now

Comment: @MartinMueller but that is rather different it is _immediately_ after `\endnumbering` (and just as the patch to `\beginnumbering` to add `\nopagebreak` would be better done as a fix to that command. None of the `\leavevmode` in your example are in that position. they are after `\chapter` and after a paragraph break (blank line)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right! I removed \leavevmode from my project completely and it now works, no clue whether this has to do with an update of reledmac or if it just has to do with me. I implemented Schweinebackes solution though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the `\leavevmode` results in extra vertical space because of an extra but empty paragraph before the section heading. It is not the problem, because it does not allow page breaks after the following `\section`.

The problem is `\pagenumbering` after `\section`. You should add/move `\nopagebreak` after `\pagenumbering`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\chapter{Letters from 1900}
\leavevmode\pagebreak[3]\section{Letter 1}
\beginnumbering\nopagebreak
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\leavevmode\pagebreak[3]\section{Letter 2}
\beginnumbering\nopagebreak
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\leavevmode\pagebreak[3]\section{Letter 3}
\beginnumbering\nopagebreak
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

However, if you really want the extra vertical space before the sections, why do you use `\leavevmode` to get it instead of using `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to increase the `beforeskip` value:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\raggedbottom
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-10ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex]{section}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Letters from 1900}
\section{Letter 1}
\beginnumbering\nopagebreak
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\section{Letter 2}
\beginnumbering\nopagebreak
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\section{Letter 3}
\beginnumbering\nopagebreak
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

If all `\beginnumbering` should avoid page breaks, you can patch the command:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\raggedbottom
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-10ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex]{section}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\beginnumbering}{\nopagebreak}{}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Letters from 1900}
\section{Letter 1}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\section{Letter 2}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\section{Letter 3}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Or you can define a new command:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\raggedbottom
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-10ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex]{section}

\newcommand\beginnumberingnobreak{\beginnumbering\nopagebreak}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Letters from 1900}
\section{Letter 1}
\beginnumberingnobreak
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\section{Letter 2}
\beginnumberingnobreak
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\section{Letter 3}
\beginnumberingnobreak
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

You could also try to detect, whether or not the `\beginnumbering` is following a `\section` or another command, that should prevent page breaks:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\raggedbottom
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-10ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex]{section}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\beginnumbering}{\if@nobreak\let\afterbeginnumbering\nopagebreak\else\let\afterbeginnumbering\relax\fi}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\beginnumbering}{\afterbeginnumbering}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Letters from 1900}
\section{Letter 1}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\section{Letter 2}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\section{Letter 3}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've settled for the new command which does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `\leavevmode` and `\nopagebreak` from the example document then the heading is not at the end of the page as the spurious white paragraphs from `\leavevmode` have gone, but if you add some more lines as below then the page does break after the heading. This is due to `\beginnumbering` and if you uncomment the redefinition then a page break at that point is prevented and one extra line stays with the heading.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\raggedbottom
\let\oldbeginnumbering\beginnumbering

%\def\beginnumbering{\oldbeginnumbering\par\nopagebreak}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Letters from 1900}
\section{Letter 1}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\section{Letter 2}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext

a\\ba\\c
\pend
\endnumbering

\section{Letter 3}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```